# Cannot install MSVS 2010 C# Express - Prerequisites x64 don't install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

On Windows 7 64bit, have had the 2010 beta installed previously (first one if my memory serves me)

http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn24/BlamBear93/MSVS2010csharpinstallerror.png

What seems to happen is this: It installs the first thing it needs to fine, then it gets to this, the bar goes all the way up and then it prompts me to reboot. After the reboot it launches itself and the bar AGAIN starts going up and pauses quarter way through.

A few seconds later it comes up with the screen above.

Any help? :)

thanks, Elliot.

Comment: Did you fully uninstall the beta before running this installer?

Comment: Well I used the uninstaller, but knowing MS it probably missed out a lot of stuff, I checked the installed programs list and all I found where the .net 4.0 installs, which I would uninstall but I'm not too sure if anything depends on them.

Comment: Blam: It usually states "you must uninstall all prerelease versions of ..." So hunt down your Programs list. Uninstall everything VS2010 and .NET4 related, then start again. IIRC I uninstalled 3 or 4 items.

Comment: Ok so I uninstalled everything I saw relating to .NET 4.0 and VS 2010, tried again. IT seemed to get further while installing the prerequisites but still came up with the same error.

The things I uninstalled seemed to be the things it installs before the prerequisites however..

Answer (score 2):

I would try tracking down the prerequisite install packages separately and installing them.  Per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/e38fc527-de56-4564-92d5-281a98349f95/ I would try the VC9 install first.

You can get the install from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29

Then move on to the .NET 4 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27758

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I would tell you if this worked but I ended up getting a new computer (unrelated issues) and I completely wiped my old one and gave it away so I can't say if it would have worked. I hope it helps anyone who has similar issues.